# Grails Multi-Tenancy with Multiple Databases

Tags: grails, multi-tenant, multiple-databases

I can't seem to find any updated resource/guide, plugin or example about Grails Multitenancy with Multiple Databases (one per tenant). I'm currently stuck with https://grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-single-db and the outdated https://grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-core.

How to perform database switching that depends on the logged-in user?

Comment: Multitenant plugins are outdated and use Hibernate 3. I have an application which is on grails 2.3 based on single db plugin. DB per tenant plugin is even more outdated. Hibernate 4 however has built in support for DB per tenant and schema per tenant based multitenancy. You can intercept gorm calls and use AST transforms to accomplish  this. But it is a time consuming job. You will have to go through Hibernate docs.

Comment: @EjazAhmed Thanks! Would probably try the Hibernate 4 approach.

Comment: @renz do you have found a working solution for this?

Comment: @lifeisfoo I used single database approach instead, much simpler. https://grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-single-db, downgraded to Hibernate 3 though.

Comment: @renz I've explored Hibernate4 a bit further and ported my grails 2.3 app to grails 3. I've created multitenant plugin for grails3 based on my work.

Comment: @EjazAhmed Nice. You should publish that on grails.org :) I wouldn't be able to use that though since porting my apps to grails 3 would not be happening anytime soon.

Comment: @EjazAhmed, I've also studied hibernate4 and it seems straightforward to implement the DB per tenant in a regular Java app. Are there any pitfalls in Grails that will put me into trouble? Is it really necessary to migrate to grails 3? Is it possible to have a look in your plugin?

Comment: @CléssioMendes the reply was not fitting in comment area so I've posted it in answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails abstracts out a lot of Hibernate stuff so there is an impedance mismatch between Gorm and Hibernate. One such problem is loading of multiple datasources based on tenant. If you go tenant per DB strategy, be prepared for a [hard battle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047346/grails-mutliple-data-source-org-springframework-beans-factory-nouniquebeandefin). Apart from complexity involved, there is a long way going forward as DB maintenance is quite costly in this strategy. Most modern applications use Single DB Single Schema approach and I've also used this approach in [my plugin](https://github.com/ejaz-ahmed/grails-multitenant-plugin). Currently this plugin resolves tenant using Spring Security. The reason for this approach was the application I was working on which was a SaaS app to be served from a single domain. If you have to serve from multiple domains, there is minor modification required in this plugin.

Regarding migration to grails3,it was released in March 2015 and over the period of one year, it has gone through various improvements and bug fixes. It is stable enough to rely on and moreover it has almost all necessary plugins already ported. If you are building a new application, you must go the grails3 way. If you have an existing application, you can consider migrating to grails3.