# Grails Multiple data source: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: grails

I recently posted a question about multiple data sources. Things were going well until I hit this issue:

Controller

```
 def doSomething() {

    def user=userService.getCurrentUser()
   }
```

Service

```
    class UserService {
     def getCurrentUser() {
        def principal = springSecurityService.principal
        String username = principal.username
        return find(username)
     }
     def find(String user) {
        return User.find{username==user}
     }
   }
```

This had been working previously on single DataSource but now with both enabled I see this on the browser:

> Error 500: Internal Server Error URI /xxx/xxx Class
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
>   Message No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 3:
>   transactionManager,transactionManager_countrycity,$primaryTransactionManager

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is now resolved.

**I think I found the issue: under grails 3 with multiple data sources if you have this import :**

> **import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional**

You will run into the above problems:

If you how ever have :

> **import grails.transaction.Transactional**

things will work as expected. I hadn;t paid attention and let ide choose wrong declaration